# Read integer file and store EACH line in ONE separate array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to read this file and store each row in one array. Can someone please tell me how to implement the code for this?

```
2
2 10 1 2 7
3 8 3 7 7 10 7
```

I have the code below and I can save every element of the text file into an array, but I need to have the lines saved into seperate arrays. How do I do this?

```
fstream myfile("myfile's_address", ios_base::in);

int a;
while (myfile >> a)
{
    word[increment] = a;
    increment++;
}
```

Comment: Is the first number in this intended to reflect the number of arrays to follow, or is it in-fact the a one-element array with a single value of `2` ?

Comment: No it's just a one-element array.

Comment: So.. something [like **this**](http://pastebin.com/ZKWZ57n1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `ifstream` instead of `fstream` with `ios_base::in`.

Next, use `std::getline()` to get one line as a string, create one vector for it (perhaps in a `vector<vector<string>>`), then parse it (perhaps using `std::istringstream`).